# how to do binding in ember from some other class but the content is in another class with Ember.Select view

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have used the following code:

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="ResAdmin.adminController.priceCategories"
                    valueBinding="selectedRestaurant.PriceCategoryID"
                    optionLabelPath="content.name"
                    optionValuePath="content.id"}}
```

for creating select list...

from the collection:

```
priceCategories: [
  {
    id: '92E9862E-DAE5-4CC8-ACDF-7E6418641F7D',
    name: "$"
  }, {
    id: '889C0E73-1587-41D5-8073-FD29FF76CF00',
    name: "$$"
  }, {
    id: '47A56B26-A64A-4967-A9F6-B9D69B2CA145',
    name: "$$$"
  }, {
    id: '417993DB-48BF-4BA9-BE0A-D6A53C6D8325',
    name: "$$$$"
  }
]
```

but i want to bind it to "selectedRestaurant.PriceCategoryID" Ember object..

How can i do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `valueBinding` to `selectionBinding`, see http://jsfiddle.net/EwGbM/

Handlebars:

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="ResAdmin.adminController"
    selectionBinding="ResAdmin.adminController.selection"
    optionLabelPath="content.name" }}

Selected: {{ResAdmin.selectedRestaurant.priceCategory.name}}
```

JS:

```
ResAdmin = Ember.Application.create({});

ResAdmin.adminController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    selection: null,
    content: [
        {
        id: '92E9862E-DAE5-4CC8-ACDF-7E6418641F7D',
        name: "$"},
    {
        id: '889C0E73-1587-41D5-8073-FD29FF76CF00',
        name: "$$"},
    {
        id: '47A56B26-A64A-4967-A9F6-B9D69B2CA145',
        name: "$$$"},
    {
        id: '417993DB-48BF-4BA9-BE0A-D6A53C6D8325',
        name: "$$$$"}
    ],
    getObjectById: function(id) {
        return this.get('content').filterProperty('id', id).get('firstObject');
    }
});

ResAdmin.selectedRestaurant = Ember.Object.create({
    priceCategoryBinding: 'ResAdmin.adminController.selection'
});

var defaultItem = ResAdmin.adminController.getObjectById('47A56B26-A64A-4967-A9F6-B9D69B2CA145');
ResAdmin.adminController.set('selection', defaultItem);
```

​

Comment: thanks for replying...that did for me..one more thing if i have to preselect the value then how would i do it? like initializing the value of PriceCategoryID:'some selected value'..then its not selecting default value

Comment: like the following code..ResAdmin = Ember.Application.create({});

ResAdmin.adminController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: [],
    priceCategories: [
        {
        id: '92E9862E-DAE5-4CC8-ACDF-7E6418641F7D',
        name: "$"},
    {
        id: '889C0E73-1587-41D5-8073-FD29FF76CF00',
        name: "$$"},
    {
        id: '47A56B26-A64A-4967-A9F6-B9D69B2CA145',
        name: "$$$"},
    {id: '417993DB-48BF-4BA9-BE0A-D6A53C6D8325',name: "$$$$"}
    ]
});
ResAdmin.selectedRestaurant = Ember.Object.create({
    PriceCategoryID: '47A56B26-A64A-4967-A9F6-B9D69B2CA145'
});

Comment: I've created a new fiddle with the functionality to manually select an item: http://jsfiddle.net/EwGbM/

Comment: That is perfectly alright ..but the thing is that i want to do it without arrayProxy the same code that you replaced before..i want everything like that but just addition of selection..

Comment: Well, then just change Ember.ArrayProxy to Ember.Object and change the binding to contentBinding="ResAdmin.adminController.content" and you should be fine